# Understanding all parameters of jQuery's getJSON() method

Tags: jquery, getjson

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

displays the syntax and available parameters of getJSON() as:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] )
```

I am learning how to use this method and all the tutorials I have come across use:

```
jQuery.getJSON( "http://path/to/file.php", function(my_results) {

// do something with the my_results variable

}
```

I have got this working, but, in my newbie mind, such an example veers off from the available parameters pretty early, the only consistency that I can see being the URL parameter.  And a `function()` is added however it is not shown in the 'available parameters' example.

Could anyone provide an example of a getJSON() method implementation where all the available parameters are used, with annotation about what each parameter is doing?

Answer (score 2):

Is it enough or you need more details?

```
$.getJSON({
  url: '/file.php',
  data: {value1:"1",value2:"2"},
  success: function(data){ console.log(data);}
});
```

Comment: What is `data: {value1:"1",value2:"2"}` representing?  Are those pairs that are being searched for in `file.php` and therefore they are the only pairs being returned? Or something else?

Comment: the values there are value-pair you will get on server value1 equal 1, they will send as get on php so you can do on server $_GET['value1'] and it will equals 1, makrk the question as resolved if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

try this example to read RSS/ATOM feed from Google Feed Proxy
**http://jsfiddle.net/ck4Ct/**

```
// Data object: RSS feed URL, number of entries to return, result format, API version
var data = {
    q: 'http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/video_and_audio/news_front_page/rss.xml'
    , num: 10
    , output: 'json'
    , v: '1.0'
};

// AJAX call to Google Feed API which converts ATOM/RSS feed to JSON
// Callback param added to url to do JSONP request
$.getJSON('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?callback=?'
            , data 
            , function (json) {
                alert(json.responseData.feed.entries[0].title)
            }
);
```